# Google maps api v2 on Cordova: not sentitive to events?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-maps-api-2

in Cordova, I would like to open a map which shows markers when initialized.
So in the code, I create the map and I wait for the event MAP_READY to add markers.
Is it the good way to do it ?

```
    var map;
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
  var button = document.getElementById("button");
  button.addEventListener("click", onBtnClicked, false);

  var div = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
  map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(div);
}, false);

map.addEventListener(plugin.google.maps.event.MAP_READY, function(map) {
    map.getMyLocation(function(location) {
        var msg = ["Current your location:\n",
            "latitude:" + location.latLng.lat,
            "longitude:" + location.latLng.lng].join("\n");

        map.addMarker({
            'position': location.latLng,
            'title': msg
            }, function(marker) {
                marker.showInfoWindow();
        });
    });
});
```

With this code, the marker is not added. But it works if I use a button with this code:

```
    map.getMyLocation(function(location) {
        var msg = ["Current your location:\n",
            "latitude:" + location.latLng.lat,
            "longitude:" + location.latLng.lng].join("\n");

        map.addMarker({
            'position': location.latLng,
            'title': msg
            }, function(marker) {
                marker.showInfoWindow();
        });
```

Thanks for your help!